# c# winForm webBrowser1.DocumentText QrCode appears corrupted in my html image

Tags: c#, winforms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8466B.png)

How to correctly display the QrCode field of the html string I display in the webBrowser1 object?

how can i solve this problem?

Is there an object related to HTML display in devexpress?

Does anyone have a better idea about displaying invoice html and xml?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.